# javascript form return but not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
 function validateForm() {
    if ($('#date').val() == "") {
        $('#date').css("border","1px solid #FF0000");
        $('#date').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if ($('#time').val() == "") {
        $('#time').css("border","1px solid #FF0000");
        $('#time').focus();
        return false
    }
    else if ($('#date').val() != "" && $('#time').val() != "") {
        var send = $.post("appointment.php",{
            package     : $('#package').val(),
            first_name  : $('#first_name').val(),
            last_name   : $('#last_name').val(),
            tel         : $('#tel').val(),
            email       : $('#email').val(),
            date        : $('#date').val(),
            time        : $('#time').val(),
        });

        send.success(function (result) {
            if (result == 'TRUE') {
                return true;
            }
            else if (result == 'FALSE') {
                return false;
            }
        });

        send.error(function () {
            alert("ajax error");
            return false;
        });

    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}

<form name="step2" id="step2" action="./step3.php" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Even when everything return false; still continue step3.php page. I had tried so many time, same result.

My appointment.php only return echo "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Any idea what's wrong in my coding?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried to stop the propagation of the event? [Look at it](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Try to call this function `return validateForm();` in submit button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because `validateForm` does not wait for your asynchronous call (`$.post`) to complete before returning.

one way of achieving what you are looking for is to always `return false`. then on success, submit manually which does not call the `onSubmit` function.

```js
function validateForm() {

  if ($('#date').val() == "") {
    $('#date').css("border", "1px solid #FF0000");
    $('#date').focus();

  } else if ($('#time').val() == "") {
    $('#time').css("border", "1px solid #FF0000");
    $('#time').focus();

  } else {

    var send = $.post("appointment.php", {
      package: $('#package').val(),
      first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
      last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
      tel: $('#tel').val(),
      email: $('#email').val(),
      date: $('#date').val(),
      time: $('#time').val(),
    });

    send.success(function(result) {

      if (result == 'TRUE') {
        $('#step2').get(0).submit();
      }

    });

  }

  return false;
}
```